# Laravel overflow when updating value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

The problem I encountered was I have a column named "timeStart" to store the unix epoch time in millisecond. When I was updating through Laravel update function, the value stored in database shows that it's negative instead of the value I wanted it to store.

e.g. value intended to store: 1540090500000
     value stored in database: -1802759264

I'm using bigint datatype here. The same code works on my localhost database but not when I uploaded it onto my shared hosting server, which is a weird issue. What can be done to address this issue?

Comment: The value you're converting to epoch is probably a date before 1 jan 1970

Comment: what type of column?

Comment: @cbaconnier I converted the time input using strtotime and I checked the output which is correct as well, I was thinking whether it's the problem for datatype, as if I put 1540090500 (second) instead of millisecond, it works perfectly. However, my main problem right now is on my localhost, it was able to store the millisecond format, but on my server, it wasn't able to do so.

Comment: @YurGasparyan BIGINT datatype

Comment: 32bit or 64bit ?

Comment: @YurGasparyan 32bit

Comment: If I put 64bit, it returns me an error saying that out of range value

Answer (score 2):

So how can I understod you are using different mysql services .
So to learn more abount 32/64bit based `bigint` please follow 
[32/64bit os BIGINT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024963/how-did-i-store-a-bigint-number-in-a-32-bit-os)

Also I will suggest you to use `string` instead of `bigint`. Some os/operations sometimes conflicts due to type `bigint`